# Display only my recent tweets not other tweets in twitter widget

Tags: twitter, twitter-widget

I have a website in which i have embedded Twitter Widget to display recent tweets.

Currently twitter widget displays all tweets related with the hashtag and @ of the user. Here i want to display the tweets by the user only not by any hashtags or @.

For example, if i want a widget of '@twitter', it shows widget like this...

[image: @twitter]

I want to show tweets only of '@twitter' which '@twitter' have posted not the other users...

Could this be possible ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several types of embedded timelines offered by Twitter, you are using the Search one. If you want to get a User Timeline, create a new widget using this URL: https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new/user

This kind of timeline will only show tweets posted by the user you set.

If you don't want (or can't) create another widget, just change the search term of your widget to: `from:@[user_handle]`. Example: `from:@TwitterDev`